# size in bytes of a vector of structs containing vector, C++

Tags: c++, memory, vector, struct

I have a data structure that is an `std::vector` of structs, where each struct also contains an `std::vector`. I want to calculate in advance an upper limit to the memory needed to represent the entire structure. TO do this, in testing I want to calculate the memory requirements for a finalized structure and compare it to my estimation.

To do this I use the following code:

```
struct SequenceInfo {
    unsigned long num1;
    unsigned long num2;
    unsigned long vectorLength;
    std::vector<unsigned long> values;
};

// A vector of sequence data to represent all data
typedef std::vector<SequenceInfo> SequenceInfoVec;
```

```
void foo(SequenceInfoVec& vec)
{
    getVec(vec);
    std::size_t actualSize = sizeof(SequenceInfoVec);

    for (SequenceInfoVec::iterator it1 = vec.begin(); it1 != vec.end(); ++it1)
    {
        actualSize += sizeof(SequenceInfo) + 
                      sizeof((*it1).values[0]) * (*it1).values.size();
    }
    cout << "memory size of vec is: " << actualSize << endl;
}
```

Is this the correct way to calculate the memory requirements of the data structure, (disregarding small OS overhead for memory allocation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty correct. But in my opinion it's best to avoid the explicit mention of types (which you already do to an extent), and replace the raw loop with a named algorithm from the standard library.

For C++14 you have [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
void foo(SequenceInfoVec& vec)
{
    getVec(vec);
    auto actualSize = std::accumulate(begin(vec), end(vec), sizeof(vec),
                    [](auto prev, auto const& item) {
                      return prev + 
                             sizeof (item) +
                             sizeof(item.values[0]) * item.values.size();
                    }
    );

    cout << "memory size of vec is: " << actualSize << endl;
}
```

And since you don't really care about the computation order, for C++ 17 you can even parallelize the computation with [`std::reduce`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce):

```
void foo(SequenceInfoVec& vec)
{
    getVec(vec);
    auto actualSize = std::reduce(std::execution::par, begin(vec), end(vec), sizeof(vec),
                    [](auto prev, auto const& item) {
                      return prev + 
                             sizeof (item) +
                             sizeof(item.values[0]) * item.values.size();
                    }
    );

    cout << "memory size of vec is: " << actualSize << endl;
}
```